# Why Do the Lua Binaries Contain .h and .c Files, but Lua IUP Binaries Contain .DLLs?

Tags: installation, lua, binaries, iup

I'm trying to update an old app that uses Lua and IUP, but I'm not very experienced, so I'm wondering if I have too many files. I originally downloaded Lua 5.4.3 and followed a tutorial on how to turn those .c and .h files into Lua.dll, Lua.exe, Lua.lib, and Luac.exe.

Then I downloaded iup-3.30-Lua54_Win64_bin.zip and extracted to it's own folder. That folder contains a bunch of .DLLs and a few .EXEs. Since those files have their own interpreter (iuplua54.exe), are the files in Lua 5.4.3 unnecessary? Why do these downloads have different file types? Did I install them wrong or did I get the wrong files?

I'm having issues with different Lua .exe files giving me different errors when I try to open a particular .lua script.

Comment: we don't know what you want to do so we cannot tell you if you have the wrong files. also you don't share any error messages so there is no help for you either. you can either download the sources and build the binaries yourself (as you did with Lua 5.4.3 or you download pre-built binaries as you did with iup.  now you have two different Lua builds. you only need one but it doesn't hurt to have two either. but if there is anything special about the iut build that you need you cannot use the standard build. the documentation will tell you

Comment: I've since downloaded some IUP libraries that have the .h files that the citybinder.c script is including (ex. `#include "iup.h"`), but they have red squiggles under them (so does "lua.h") in VSCode. I set up my environmental variables in path, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.